# How To hide MemberPress weekly stats from dashboard of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

**Is there a way to  hide MemberPress  weekly stats from dashboard of wordpress**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'Screen Options', once that is open, you will see radio-buttons of all that is on your screen.
These radio-buttons allow you to turn off or on any widget that is on the dashboard. For the Stats plugin, deselect the button. When you close the 'Screen Options' window, Stats will be gone.